# How to open cash drawer in C# application?

Tags: c#

I make an application for supermarket using barcode and I need to open cash drawer via click button in C#.

This code to save data and print receipt.

```
private void btnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    try {
        this.txtOredrId.Text = barcode.GET_LAST_ORDER_ID_BARCODE().Rows[0][0].ToString();
        barcode.ADD_ORDER_BARCODE(Convert.ToInt32(txtOredrId.Text), txtDate.Value, txtdesc.Text, txtSalesMan.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvProducts.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            barcode.ADD_ORDER_DETAILS_BARCODE(Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(txtOredrId.Text),Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value), Convert.ToInt32(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value), dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
                );

        }

        //MessageBox.Show("تم الحفظ بنجاح", "الحفظ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        ClearData();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        int order_ID = Convert.ToInt32(barcode.GET_LAST_ORDERBARCODE_For_Print().Rows[0][0]);
        RPT.rpt_orders_barcode report = new RPT.rpt_orders_barcode();
        RPT.FRM_RPT_PRODUCT frm = new RPT.FRM_RPT_PRODUCT();
        report.SetDataSource(barcode.GetOrderBarcodeDetails(order_ID));
        frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        frm.ShowDialog();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I need code to open cash drawer.

Comment: What's `barcode`?  What's `dgvProducts`? Why are crystal reports involved with opening a cash drawer?  What even is the cash drawer?

Comment: You can always use a key!!!

Answer (score 8):

Method to open a cash drawer depends on the way the cash drawer is connected to the application PC. Cash drawers can be connected directly to the till or through a USB or Serial Printer.

1. If cash drawer is connected directly, we can make use of the Microsoft POS for .Net library.
2. Cash drawer connected through a USB Printer - make use of the Printer API, for example STAR or EPSON have got their own library to interact with the cash drawer, get status etc.
3. Cash drawer connected through a Serial Printer - just send a byte array to fire the cash drawer open command, like below:

   ```
   byte[] buffer = new byte[5]
   {
     (byte) 27,
     (byte) 112,
     (byte) 0,
     (byte) 25,
     (byte) 250
    };
   //port is an instance of a Serial Port
    this.port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   ```

Please find further reference to the write method at:

[SerialPort.Write Method (Byte[], Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Encoding enc = Encoding.Unicode;
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM4";
            sp.Encoding = enc;
            sp.BaudRate = 38400;
            sp.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            sp.DtrEnable = true;
            sp.Open();
            sp.Write(char.ConvertFromUtf32(28699) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(9472) + char.ConvertFromUtf32(3365));
            sp.Close();

Answer (score 2):

This is a vendor-specific problem. You need the documentation for the cash drawer vendor's API and/or device driver to know how to instruct it to open or close.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked in bpos thermal printer.Also Work with printer support drawer(usb )
***Using Vb.net***
please use this sample
[https://github.com/lavahasif/opendrawvb.net][1]

```html
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1
    Public Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
        Const ESC As String = ChrW(27)
        Const p As String = "p"
        Const m As String = vbNullChar
        Const t1 As String = "%"
        Const t2 As String = "ɐ"
        Const openTillCommand As String = ESC & p & m & t1 & t2
'        printer("POS-X Thermal Printer")
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("POS-X Thermal Printer", openTillCommand)
    End Sub
 
End Module
```

```html
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class RawPrinterHelper
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet := CharSet.Ansi)>
    Public Class DOCINFOA
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public pDocName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public pOutputFile As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> Public pDataType As String
    End Class

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError := True, CharSet := CharSet.Ansi,
             ExactSpelling := True, CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(
                                       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal szPrinter As String,
                                       <Out> ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "ClosePrinter", SetLastError := True, ExactSpelling := True,
             CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function ClosePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError := True, CharSet := CharSet.Ansi,
             ExactSpelling := True, CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function StartDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal level As Int32,
                                           <[In], MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal di As DOCINFOA) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError := True, ExactSpelling := True,
             CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function EndDocPrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError := True, ExactSpelling := True,
             CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function StartPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError := True, ExactSpelling := True,
             CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function EndPagePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <
        DllImport _
            ("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint := "WritePrinter", SetLastError := True, ExactSpelling := True,
             CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function WritePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32,
                                        <Out> ByRef dwWritten As Int32) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SendBytesToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr,
                                              ByVal dwCount As Int32) As Boolean
        Dim dwError As Int32 = 0, dwWritten As Int32 = 0
        Dim hPrinter As IntPtr = New IntPtr(0)
        Dim di As DOCINFOA = New DOCINFOA()
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
        di.pDocName = "drawer"
        di.pDataType = "RAW"

        If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero) Then

            If StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) Then

                If StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) Then
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
                End If

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
            End If

            ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
        End If

        If bSuccess = False Then
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
        End If

        Return bSuccess
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SendFileToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szFileName As String) As Boolean
        Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open)
        Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
        Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False
        Dim pUnmanagedBytes As IntPtr = New IntPtr(0)
        Dim nLength As Integer
        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength)
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength)
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength)
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes)
        Return bSuccess
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SendStringToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal szString As String) As Boolean
        Dim pBytes As IntPtr
        Dim dwCount As Int32
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1)*Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString)
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount)
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes)
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

***Using c#***

```html
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string pDataType;
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter,
        IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
        ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }

            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }

        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;

        // How many characters are in the string?
        // Fix from Nicholas Piasecki:
        // dwCount = szString.Length;
        dwCount = (szString.Length + 1) * Marshal.SystemMaxDBCSCharSize;

        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ESC = "\u001B";
            const string p = "\u0070";
            const string m = "\u0000";
            const string t1 = "\u0025";
            const string t2 = "\u0250";
            const string openTillCommand = ESC + p + m + t1 + t2;

            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("Bill", openTillCommand);
        }
```

https://github.com/lavahasif/openprintercsha

Answer (score 1):

[How to program a cash drawer to open using Escape commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv72E.jpg)
http://www.beaglehardware.com/howtoprogramcashdrawer.html

The way to open the cash drawer via ESC/POS command (if your printer is compatible with this) requires a hexadecimal value sent as a string.

The following has been tested and works, you will need your own implementation for the print function (SendStringToPrinter)

> //Printer name is the name of the printer connected to your cash
>   drawer

```
const string ESC = "\u001B";
const string p = "\u0070";
const string m = "\u0000";
const string t1 = "\u0025";
const string t2 = "\u0250";
const string openTillCommand = ESC + p + m + t1 + t2;

SendStringToPrinter(printerName, openTillCommand);
```